# Customizing eprints with conventional .bst bibtex styles

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am fairly happy with the way I can customize eprint references with Biblatex/biber, see below. I would like to know whether there is a way to achieve a similar result by solely relying on the possibly adapted but conventional bibtex styles (unsrt, plain...). I am aware of the various [arXiv-compliant bibtex styles](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/) but it seems to me that managing distinct eprint styles in the same document is not straightforward if not impossible with bibtex.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{doic}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{arkc}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{oaic}{red!50!black}
\colorlet{hdlc}{yellow!50!black}
\colorlet{arxivc}{pink!50!black}
\usepackage[hyperref=true,backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{sf}

\title{Various eprint styles with Biblatex}

% DOI links
\def\doitourl#1{http://dx.doi.org/#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \ifhyperref
      {\color{doic}\href{\doitourl#1}{[doi:\nolinkurl{#1}]}}
      {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

% ARK links
\def\arktourl#1{http://gallica.bnf.fr/#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:ark}{%
    \ifhyperref
        {\color{arkc}\href{\arktourl#1}{[\nolinkurl{#1}]}}
        {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

% OAI links
\def\oaitourl#1{http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:oai}{%
    \ifhyperref
        {\color{oaic}\href{\oaitourl#1}{[oai:\nolinkurl{#1}]}}
        {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

% Orbi.lu links
\def\hdltourl#1{http://hdl.handle.net/#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:hdl}{%
    \ifhyperref
        {\color{hdlc}\href{\hdltourl#1}{[hdl:\nolinkurl{#1}]}}
        {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

% ARXIV links       
\def\arxivtourl#1{http://arxiv.org/abs/#1}      
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
    \ifhyperref
        {\color{arxivc}\href{\arxivtourl#1}{[arxiv:\nolinkurl{#1}]}}
        {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

together with the `ref.bib` file (I've truncated the titles for compactness)

```
@article{Ba,
 year={2000},
 journal={Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis},
 volume={154},
 number={3},
 doi={10.1007/s002050000105},
 title={The Dynamics of Discrete Mechanical Systems},
 publisher={Springer-Verlag},
 author={Patrick Ballard},
 pages={199-274},
 eprinttype = {oai},
 eprint = {hal-00111308}}

@ARTICLE{Beylkin92,
  author = {Nguyen, Vinh-Phu},
  title = {Nitsche's method for two and three dimensional NURBS},
  journal = {Computational Mechanics},
  year = {2015},
  volume = {29},
  pages = {1716-1740},
  number = {6},
  eprint = {10993/13771},
  eprinttype = {hdl}}

@ARTICLE{Williams94,
  author = {C. Pfrommer},
  title = {Simulating cosmic ray physics on a moving mesh},
  journal = {International Journal for Numerical Methods in Engineering},
  eprint = {1604.07399},
  eprinttype = {arxiv}}

@book{Lame,
  title={Le\c{c}ons sur la théorie mathématique de l'élasticité des corps solides},
  author={Lamé, Gabriel},
  eprint= {ark:/12148/bpt6k5747708p},
  eprinttype = {ark},
  year={1852},
  publisher={Bachelier},
  address={Paris}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's entirely possible to set this up by editing a standard `.bst` file, it's just somewhat tedious. There are three things needed. First, you need to tell BibTeX to make entries `doi`, `eprint` and `eprinttype` available by modifying the `ENTRY` list:

```
ENTRY {
  ...
  doi
  eprint
  eprinttype
  ...
}
```

Second, you need a function that is going to do the formatting. Exactly how you set this up will depend on whether you want all the bells and whistles. For example, adding a switch to detect `hyperref` makes life a bit more complex. In the following, I'll assume that `hyperref` will always be loaded. I'm also assuming in the following that we can take the types of `eprinttype` from the above and that it's all reliable (all entries will be of known types, `\<eprinttype>tourl` and `<eprinttype>c` colours will be defined in the document, *etc.*). That leads to something like the following

```
FUNCTION {format.doi.eprint}
{
  doi empty$
    'skip$
    {
      "\textcolor{doic}{\href{\doitourl{" doi * "}}{[doi:\nolinkurl{" * doi * "}]}}" *
      eprint empty$
        'skip$
        { output }
      if$
    }
  if$
  eprint empty$
  eprinttype empty$
  and not
    {
      "\textcolor{" eprinttype * "c}{\href{\" * eprinttype * "tourl{" *
         eprint * "}}{[" * eprinttype * ":\nolinkurl{" * eprint * "}]}}" *
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

Finally, the function has to be added into the output of entry types. You could do that by adding it on to an existing general function such as that for the `note` field, but I'd do it manually:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.doi.eprint output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Depending on the sophistication required, one could add sanity tests, pass data concerning known types to BibTeX, *etc*.

---

Editing the above into `plain.bst`, renamed as `eplain.bst`, and using the example source

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Ba,
 year={2000},
 journal={Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis},
 volume={154},
 number={3},
 doi={10.1007/s002050000105},
 title={The Dynamics of Discrete Mechanical Systems},
 publisher={Springer-Verlag},
 author={Patrick Ballard},
 pages={199-274},
 eprinttype = {oai},
 eprint = {hal-00111308}}

@ARTICLE{Beylkin92,
  author = {Nguyen, Vinh-Phu},
  title = {Nitsche's method for two and three dimensional NURBS},
  journal = {Computational Mechanics},
  year = {2015},
  volume = {29},
  pages = {1716-1740},
  number = {6},
  eprint = {10993/13771},
  eprinttype = {hdl}}

@ARTICLE{Williams94,
  author = {C. Pfrommer},
  title = {Simulating cosmic ray physics on a moving mesh},
  journal = {International Journal for Numerical Methods in Engineering},
  eprint = {1604.07399},
  eprinttype = {arxiv}}

@book{Lame,
  title={Le\c{c}ons sur la théorie mathématique de l'élasticité des corps solides},
  author={Lamé, Gabriel},
  eprint= {ark:/12148/bpt6k5747708p},
  eprinttype = {ark},
  year={1852},
  publisher={Bachelier},
  address={Paris}}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{doic}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{arkc}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{oaic}{red!50!black}
\colorlet{hdlc}{yellow!50!black}
\colorlet{arxivc}{pink!50!black}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{sf}

\def\doitourl#1{http://dx.doi.org/#1}
\def\arktourl#1{http://gallica.bnf.fr/#1}
\def\oaitourl#1{http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/#1}
\def\hdltourl#1{http://hdl.handle.net/#1}
\def\arxivtourl#1{http://arxiv.org/abs/#1}   
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{eplain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

generates essentially the same output as in the question.

Comment: Whilst BibTeX  is limited in some ways (non-ASCII input, fixed data model, _etc._), the stack language is perfectly capable of managing this type of programming problem. The issue comes in that it has to be set up in every `.bst` file you want to use.

Comment: @pluton I've fixed various errors in the example: it now works if I add the three lines to `ENTRY`, add the one line to `FUNCTION {article}` and insert `FUNCTION {format.doi.eprint}` just before `FUNCTION {article}`.

Comment: Superb! Does the `FUNCTION {format.doi.eprint}` has to be necessarily placed right before `FUNCTION {article}` or anywhere else before would be fine?

Comment: @pluton Anywhere _before_ the first use (unlike TeX, BibTeX does care about this). So somewhere in the set of `format.<thing>` functions seems sensible.